# http request in windows phone 7 generating System.Net.WebException exception

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am new in windows phone platform.I was trying to send a http request and print the response.I created a simple WP 7 project tried  webClient with the code

```
  var client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, ev) => {System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( ev.Result); };

        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));`
```

But it is producing this error

> {System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
>      at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClasse.b*_d(Object sendState)
>      at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0(Object sendState)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
>      at System.Net.DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()
>      at PanoramaApp2.MainPage.<.ctor>b__0(Object s, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs ev)
>      at System.Net.WebClient.OnDownloadStringCompleted(DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadStringOperationCompleted(Object arg)}

I tried with HttpWebRequest too.But also generates exception.I spend a lot of time to solve this but still cant get a reponse from http request.please help me out.

Comment: I tried the same but there is no problem in the code. I got the result and error is null.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when developing a Windows Store App for Win 8. It turned out I had to give the app permission to access the internet/network